# Summarise a vector and then append the summary statistics to the original dataframe in R

Tags: r, reshape2, summary, dplyr

**Intro:**

I would like to compute the mean, standard deviation, and standard error of a numeric vector in a given dataframe and then create three new vectors using these summary statistics. I then need to combine them with the original dataframe.

**Example Code:**

```
## Creating our dataframe:
datetime <- c("5/12/2017 16:15:00","5/16/2017 16:45:00","5/19/2017 17:00:00")
datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
values <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(datetime, values)

## Here's the current output:
head(df)
             datetime values
1 2017-05-12 16:15:00      1
2 2017-05-16 16:45:00      2
3 2017-05-19 17:00:00      3

## And here's the desired output:
head(df1)
             datetime values mean    sd    se
1 2017-05-12 16:15:00      1    2 0.816 0.471
2 2017-05-16 16:45:00      2    2 0.816 0.471
3 2017-05-19 17:00:00      3    2 0.816 0.471
```

Thanks in advance!

For those who are curious as to why I am trying to do this, I am following this [tutorial](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/). I need to make one of those line graph plots with errorbars for some calibrations between a low-cost sensor and an expensive reference instrument.

Comment: Create the new column and assign the mean like this: `df$mean <- mean(df$values)`. Follow the same procedure for `sd` and the last column

Comment: Wow, that was too easy, thank you! I should have known better... I was stuck trying to figure out how to do this with dplyr...

Comment: alternatively: `sd0 <- function(x){sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)) * sqrt(length(x) - 1)};
se0 <- function(x){ sd0(x) / sqrt(length(x))};

df2[c('mean', 'se', 'sd')] <- lapply(list(mean, se0, sd0), function(f) f(df$values))
`

Comment: Nice! I definitely need to get more comfortable with `lapply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the assignment simultaneously. Suppose you already have the helper function for you choice of `sd` and `se`:

```
sd0 <- function(x){sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)) * sqrt(length(x) - 1)}
se0 <- function(x){ sd0(x) / sqrt(length(x))}
```

Then you can try:

```
df[c('mean', 'sd', 'se')] <- lapply(list(mean, sd0, se0), function(f) f(df$values))
# > df
#              datetime values mean        sd        se
# 1 2017-05-12 16:15:00      1    2 0.8164966 0.4714045
# 2 2017-05-16 16:45:00      2    2 0.8164966 0.4714045
# 3 2017-05-19 17:00:00      3    2 0.8164966 0.4714045
```

Comment: @spacedSparking, out of curiosity, why you use a biased estimate instead of the default `sd` in R.

Comment: That's a good question... I'm getting slightly different numbers between `df$sd <- sd(df$values)` and the `sd0` function. I'm seeing `1` versus `0.81` for sd, and `0.57` and `0.47` for se... It appears that the `sd()` function provides the sample standard deviation, while the `sd0()` function provides the population standard deviation... Does that sound about right?

Comment: This because `sd` use `sqrt(n - 1)` as denominator. FYI, see manual of `?sd` and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `dplyr` solution, with `sd0` and `se0` given in `mt1022`'s answer:

```
df %>% mutate("mean"=mean(values),"sd"=sd0(values),"se"=se0(values))
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for sharing!